# Push Notification does not generate the ChannelUri while using on the device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, push-notification, mpns

I'm trying to implement push tile notifications in my application, to understand the working i have made a sample app by using code given in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202970%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_CreatingaPushClienttoReceiveTileNotifications). Now my problem is when i run the application in the simulator everything goes fine, i even get the url that i'm supposed to receive, but when i run the app on device (even after uninstalling and  rebooting the device) i keep on getting the same error

> The channel does not exist, but could not be opened.  Try opening the channel again.

Is there something i'm missing ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a different device to try this on? The few cases where I've run into this, the user had to do a hard reset of their device, and then everything just worked. I've seen somewhere suggested to confirm that the date/time/timezone setting on your device is set correctly. I'm not too hopeful for it, but it would be great if you say that it resolved your problem!